# Semantic difference between regular and irregular 'backen'

Tags: irregular-verb

Is there a difference in meaning between the preterite *buk*, from *backen*, and *backte*?

If so what is it?

Thanks

Comment: I feel that answers should at least mention https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/backen_herstellen_garen vs https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/backen_festhaengen_ankleben. Source: I have had German classes at school.

Answer (score 9):

The text [*Backte* oder *buk*, *haute* oder *hieb*? - Schwache oder starke Flexion](https://ids-pub.bsz-bw.de/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/5778/file/Kubczak_Backte_buk_2016_4.pdf) by Jacqueline Kubczak (published in Sprachreport, Jg. 32 (2016), H. 4, S. 24-31) goes into great detail about *backte* vs. *buk*. Quoting its gist:

> Die Formen *buk*/*buken* sind im heutigen geschriebenen Deutsch noch lebendig. Man findet sie nicht nur in literarischen, sondern auch in eher umgangssprachlich geschriebenen Texten. In der alltäglichen gesprochenen Sprache muten die starken Formen von *backen* aber doch altmodisch oder gestelzt an.

So, apart from the fact that *buk* is considered archaic in some contexts there is no difference in meaning.

Answer (score 4):

For those verbs which have both a strong and a weak *Präteritum* form, there is generally no difference in meaning. That's true for *backen* et al.

Be careful however, as there are a lot of verbs which have very similar cousins:

> liegen, es lag, gelegen
>
> legen, es legte, gelegt
>
> lügen, es log, gelogen
>
> lugen, es lugte, gelugt
>
> laugen, es laugte, gelaugt *(auslaugen and entlaugen are meaningful)*

For such verbs, you may misidentify the weak form as a modern replacement of the strong form, when it's actually two different verbs. The *legen*←→*liegen* misinterpretation is especially common as those verbs mean a very similar thing.

Comment: Note that that last one is especially tricky for native speakers of English, since English is in the process of losing the distinction between the homologous "lie"/"lay" as well.

Comment: There are pairs of similar verbs where the strong one is intransitive and the weak one is transitive: Stehen/stellen, liegen/legen.

Comment: @RHa Some more: fahren/führen, sitzen/setzen, hängen/hängen, fallen/fällen, biegen (can be both by now) / beugen (can only be transitive), erschrecken/erschrecken. Not, btw, schleifen/schliff/geschliffen and schleifen/schleifte/geschleift.

Comment: springen/sprengen (man *Kausativ*)

Answer (score 3):

"buk" is just an archaic form of "backte", both are past tense of "backen"

Source: I am German